# How to create icons similar to Segoe MDL2 Assets in UWP

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

as I said, Segoe MDL2 Assets has many icons, but not enough. Usually we want to use our own icons.

But there is one problem, our own icons can't auto suite for both light and dark themes, while the segoe icons can.

So, anybody know how? Thanks :)

[image]

[image]

Comment: How do you create your own icons?

Comment: @Filip Skakun I usually create png files using photoshop, and then convert to ico files

Comment: I don't recommend raster icons unless it's impossible to get same effects with vector-based ones. You might be better off creating .ai icons in Illustrator and then converting those to xaml or xvg (see [`SvgImageSource`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.svgimagesource)). Otherwise - you can still provide a separate image resource for each theme (see [`ThemeDictionaries`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.resourcedictionary#Windows_UI_Xaml_ResourceDictionary_ThemeDictionaries)). Note though you'd need an image for each theme and res

Comment: At least each theme and resolution you'd like to support. This could result with a bloated appx package or a need to generate a bunch of resources and optional packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the icon font to be of the right color you'll have to export as a font (i.e. **ttf**) and not as **ico**

There are few online tools to convert your PNG assets to a font file

- https://icomoon.io/app/#/select
- http://fontastic.me/

Once you have a font file you can use it in your app, specifying the font family in XAML

`<TextBlock Text="&#xEB52; FontFamily="/Assets/Fonts/my-font.ttf#My Font"/>`

You can also create a new **FontFamily** if you don't want to specify the path each time
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.fontfamily

Answer (score 2):

I may be wrong, but if you use your own custom font - the icons should get appropriate colors (assuming that your font isn't already colored). If you just use a `Path` element - you'd probably need to specify a `ThemeResource` for its `Foreground` and define theme specific resources (or just use one that the platform provides).

Comment: Thanks, I will give it try